# Calling external JS function from internal JS code block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 JS blocks that I am working with.  One is internal to my HTML.  It handles touch functionality. The other is an external file which is a content slider.  Basically I want to use the touchevents to control the slider and move to the previous/next slide depending on which direction the user swipes on mobile devices but have more traditional controls on desktops. Is it possible to call a function in the external file from my internal code block.

HTML File

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/externalfile.js"></script>
<script>
... lots of code for touchevents ....

function processingRoutine() {

    if ( swipeDirection == 'left' ) {
        // Function below is in external file
        previous();

    } else if ( swipeDirection == 'right' ) {
        // Function below is in external file
        next();

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
Some HTML code
</body>
```

External JS File

```
(function($) {

...  Functionality to work slider ...

    // load the next slide
    // These are the functions I am trying to call from above.
function next() {
    goToAndPause(counter+1);
};

// load the previous slide
function previous() {
    goToAndPause(counter-1);
};

})(jQuery);
```

Is there an easy way to do this or is there a rotator that has this functionality built in already?

Comment: No, this is impossible and this is by design. For some reason, the guy who wrote that plugin didn't think you deserve that functionality :P

Answer (score 0):

The slider must have been instantiated somehow and you may have a reference to it, i.e. to make the slider work in the first place you might have called something like `$('.mySlider').slider();` 
if you changed that to 
`window.mySlider = $('.mySlider').slider();` 
you could then potentially then call `mySlider.next()` or similar in your "internal" code.

Answer (score 0):

why not just extract your code into an external js file? I don't see any reason you would actually need to have it embedded in the script tag , and in general i think that may be a poor architectural decision.

2nd idea, you could also get to it by declaring a global variable and accessing it, though thats not great practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind editing the plugin, you could use jQuery's event API.

```
// external file

(function($) {

    ....

    $(window).on('slider:next', next);

    $(window).on('slider:previous', previous);

})(jQuery);


// inline js (this should really live in its own file, too)

function processingRoutine () {

    if ( swipeDirection === 'left' ) {

        $(window).trigger('slider:next');

    } else if ( swipeDirection === 'right' ) {

        $(window).trigger('slider:previous');

    }

}
```